# Webcam Conference // Software to modify picture

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, webcam

is there any software to modify my webcam picture? I tried to find something, but only found software that has "fun" filters.

#### The Task

I need the software to run video conferences and do workshops that were planned to be on-site. These need to be done remote now. In order to have a professional appearance and help the team to focus, I need a tool to help me by having features like the following:

- Clock Timer for Countdowns or Count Ups
- Put my logo into the webcam picture (like a watermark)
- Put other graphics into the webcam picture (like moderation notes "enough, lets move on!" etc.)

I will probably use MS Teams as conferencing software most of the times, but this will not always be the case. So the perfect solution should generally override the webcam picture, which would make it able to use with every conferencing tool.

It is also okay, if the software is quite hard to get into, since I plan to use it a lot. It will be worth the time. The technical expertise is quite high since I am quite proficient in using and configuring software tools.

#### What I already found

I already found OBS (https://obsproject.com/), but it requires a windows-only plugin to be able to stream directly to the webcam (https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.539/).

It is also okay, if the software is not for free.

Does anybody know a solution for me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please see https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation for details about how to ask for software recommendations.

Comment: @nohillside beat me to it.  Yes.  Please read that Meta post because there's lots of details missing (i.e. your technical expertise, etc.).  That said, have a look at [OBS](https://obsproject.com/).  It's powerful, but you'll need to invest some time into it.

Comment: Hi, I adjusted the initial post to fit the requirements. Please review again. I also added a note regarding OBS. The required plugin is only available for Windows.